# How to close Bootstrap modal only when user clicks on close image?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to close modal ONLY when user clicks on close btn. As I see I need to overwrite this part of code from modal.js:

```
 hide: function (e) {
    e && e.preventDefault()

    var that = this

    e = $.Event('hide')//if I delete this line modal won't hide

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = false

    $('body').removeClass('modal-open')

    escape.call(this)

    this.$element.removeClass('in')

    $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      hideWithTransition.call(this) :
      hideModal.call(this)
```

Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When you launch your modal you can pass the options:

```
{
  keyboard: false,
  backdrop: 'static'
}
```

which will disable closing the modal by clicking the backdrop, and the escape-button.
Or they can be set as `data-`attributes.

Comment: @Normal, I've already found it thanks. Now, I can't close previous modal, when calling another one (login -> forgot password), because of static option and when I remove static attribute and hide it fade efect stays. Can you help me if I create jsfiddle ?

Comment: I can't even OPEN modal from modal in jsfiddle. Please look here - http://jsfiddle.net/sfWBT/493/

Comment: This switches the modal, and nothing more. No backdrop on the second modal, and it is positioned weird here, but might be used as a basis for further tweaks: http://jsfiddle.net/AWSc6/

Comment: Example using the `data-` attributes: `<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">`

Answer (score 85):

You can define your modal behavior, defining data-keyboard and data-backdrop.

```
 <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this one

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in" data-backdrop="static">
<div> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

The best way to make it in Jquery is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#modal-id').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
</script>
```

OR in HTML:

```
<div id="modal-id" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

But, if you already have initialized the modal you need unbind the click event of your modal like this for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //this remove the close button on top if you need
    $('#modal-id').find('.close').remove();
    //this unbind the event click on the shadow zone
    $('#modal-id').unbind('click');
</script>
```

Comment: Your second example (for already initialized modals) doesn't handle dismissing of the modal by pressing the escape key.

Comment: It is true , for this reason , i had written this : "But, if you already have initialized the modal you need unbind the click event of your modal like this for example" ...  For me it works =D

Comment: @johnnyRose if it's necessary disabled key-Events `$('#modal-id').unbind('keyEventName') ;` should help you

Answer (score 3):

You can define your modal behavior, defining data-keyboard and data-backdrop.

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

And Moreover this, it also works in ASPX Pages.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use no-close-backdrop

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" no-close-on-backdrop no-close-on-keyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 5 you can add attributes to your modal to handle it:

```
<div class="modal id="staticBackdrop" 
     data-bs-backdrop="static" 
     data-bs-keyboard="false">
    < ... >
</div>
```

Here's a link to the docs for the full story:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#static-backdrop